# Find examples of countable infinite sets S and T such that S\T is finite.

Tags: logic

I'm beginning an introductory logic courses and I'm having trouble figuring this question out.

I have to find an example of countable infinite sets such that:

(a) $S$ \ $T$ is finite

and

(b) $|S$ \ $T| = 8$

There was a third part where $S$ \ $T$ had to be infinite, so I set $S$ to the set of all integers and $T$ to the set of real numbers, making (what I think) $S$ \ $T$ the set of negative numbers.

Any help on figuring how to go about this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Your solution to the third problem makes no sense; the set of integers is *contained* in the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S=\{1,2,3,...\}$ and $T=\{9,10,...\}$ are both countable infinite sets. Their difference,
$$S\setminus T=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\},$$

is finite and it has exactly $8$ elements.

For the third case, take $S=\{\pm1, \pm 2,...\}$ and $T=\{1,2,...\}$. (And not necessarily the positive  reals.)